# How to delay window closing in WPF

Tags: wpf, timer, window, threadpool

I try to delay close a window in my App.xaml.ca :

```
Window splash = new Window();
splash.Show();

Timer timer = new Timer(callback, null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);

private void callback(object stateInfo)
{
  splash.Close();
}
```

It works fine, but the whole App is shutdowning. What am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why would you want an app to pause before shutting down?  This goes against the expected behavior in Windows, which means it is a bad design.  It will also make people think your program is laggy.  If you are thinking of adding a close confirmation dialog, see this chapter in Joel Spolsky's UI design book: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html (towards the end, where it says `many people are intimidated by computers`)

Comment: Oh, you're trying to implement a splash screen that closes itself...  Can you edit your question to make that more obvious, possibly stating that in the first sentence? :)  It makes it much quicker to figure out what you are asking.  Along these lines, you may also want to make your app appear over your splash screen.  Making your app *start up* slowly will just irk users.

Comment: I will eventually edit it. But you must not mix Window and App. I try to close a Window, not the App. But when I do close the window, the App is closing too, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to check that you timer callback is coming back on the main dispatcher thread. If not then you will likely be getting an exception when you try to close your window from a different thread.

Use `splash.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` to make sure you are on the right thread and if not then use `splash.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) () => splash.Close()` to dispatch the call onto the main thread.

Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S5) for more

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to this exact same problem:

```
 private async void CloseWindow()
 {
    await ClosingTasks();
 }

 private async Task ClosingTasks()
 {            
    await Task.Delay(2000);            
    this.Close();
 }
```

Where you simply call CloseWindow() when you want to close the current window after the given delay of 2000 mS.

Answer (score 1):

There are different shutdown modes, if that window is closed and it is the last then the application will shut down by default. So you can either see to it that there is still some window around or you can change the shutdown behaviour by setting the `ShutdownMode` to something that suits your needs.

e.g.

```
Application.Current.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it'd be wise to leave it that way and not change it. Just instantiate your main-menu window, show it and hide the splash :)